# kotlin: How to get the field name which in Object?

Tags: spring, kotlin, kotlin-reflect

I have a `@ConfigurationProperties` class, like `ConfigProperty`. I use it like

> org.springframework.ui.Model#addAttribute("config1", configProperty.config1)
>   org.springframework.ui.Model#addAttribute("config2", configProperty.config2)

I don't want repeat myself. So I want to it like this:

> Model#addAttribute(::configProperty.config1.name, configProperty.config1)
>   Model#addAttribute(::configProperty.config2.name, configProperty.config2)

But the syntax is wrong, anyone has some suggestions?

Comment: Did you read somewhere that this **would** work?

Comment: Not find anywhere talk about it, so submit a question for it

Comment: `configProperty::config1.name` would also work. For your initial question, note "yet" in the error text.

Comment: @Subzero I had modify this question for my condition~~~

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Thank you~

Comment: Please, answer your own question in an _Answer_ and validate it. It will help this site.

Answer (score 0):

After this question, I find that the syntax is wrong. I should use it like:

```
Model#addAttribute(ConfigProperty::config1.name, configProperty.config1) 
Model#addAttribute(ConfigProperty::config2.name, configProperty.config2)
```

Thanks for everybody~